# Show data in recyclerview from two diffrent tables

Tags: android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

Hello guys can anyone help me to implement Recyclerview using two database table's (like users and posts). Am making Search in my project where user can find persons and post. Here is an Example :

[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIIdm.png)

in above link there is an image where first two rows are user and after that all are posts. I want somthing like that. I know how to join RecyclerView with a single table and need **Hint** to join two or more table to a single RecyclerView. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a different list item?

Comment: i solved that by using 2 recyclerview